# Nginx regex alias on common location

Tags: nginx, regex, alias

I am trying to recursively serve the content of a folder for several customer IDs to pertain backwards compatibility to a respective application beyond my influence.
I want all URLs paths beginning with `/<integer_customer_id>/<integer_display_id>/config/<whatever...>` to be serving the files `/var/cache/digsig/config/<whatever...>`.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
location ~ ^/[0-9]+/[0-9]+/config/ {
    alias /var/cache/digsig/config/;
}
```

Resulting in:

```
$ wget http://localhost:/993002/104/config/config.ini
--2016-12-07 12:08:57--  http://localhost/993002/104/config/config.ini
Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:80... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://localhost/993002/104/config/config.ini/ [following]
--2016-12-07 12:08:57--  http://localhost/993002/104/config/config.ini/
Reusing existing connection to localhost:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2016-12-07 12:08:57 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

The log says:

```
2016/12/07 12:08:57 [error] 8232#8232: *4 directory index of "/var/cache/digsig/config/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /993002/104/config/config.ini/ HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
```

Why is the alias directive *moved permanently* and why does it get added a `/` at the end, destroying the actual path?
Please note that I do not have *any* `return 301 ...` statements in my entire Nginx configuration.

Comment: http://nginx.org/r/alias «If alias is used inside a location defined with a regular expression then such regular expression should contain captures and alias should refer to these captures»

Comment: What is the configuration of the complete `server` block?